# How to attach a Java application to jvm profiler in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, monitoring

I want to memory-profile my Java application with jvm monitor. All docs seem to assume that your application runs on a server. For example, the first picture on http://www.jvmmonitor.org/doc/ shows an application running on "localhost". But I just run my application in eclipse with "Run as -> java application", so my application doesn't appear in the list of servers.

Answer (score 0):

From the FAQ, linked from the docs in your question: [Why can I not find any jvms on jvm explorer?](http://www.jvmmonitor.org/doc/#Cannot_Find_JVMs)

JVMs started in eclipse are running on your localhost, by definition. It's not that they are running in an app server, necessarily.